# Reading .pcap files by CISCO ASA5515-X

Tags: networking, cisco, cisco-asa, network-monitoring, security

I have .pcap file that already includes thousands of packets. I want to analyze these packets via CISCO ASA5515-X to observe how much of them are possible to be an attack packet (malicious). However, I could not succeed to read the .pcap file. I am using IcedTea - Cisco ASDM 6.6 for ASA. Wizard -> Packet capture wizards do not have an option to load and read the pcap file and I could not find an alternative way.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thank you for your helps in advance.

Regards
Eray

Comment: You should be able to open the file in Wirshark and view it, or you can upload it here and view it: https://appliance.cloudshark.org/upload/

Comment: if you want to just open it, Wireshark is one option.
However you might have only downloaded the textual version of the file.

see https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/10717591/asa-capture-files-not-being-read-wireshark

Comment: Yea, Wireshark opens it. But how can I use CISCO ASA5515-X router in wireshark to analyze which packets are malicious? Is there any way for that?

Thank you for the links by the way.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the router only analyzes live traffic. However, you can turn a pcap file into live traffic via tcprewrite and tcpreplay. Those tools let you change the endpoints, recalculate checksums, and send the traffic back through your router for analysis. I would pick two test hosts for your new endpoints such that replaying from one will result in the replayed traffic being routed through the device in question.